# Binded mysql statement with case-sensitifity function "LOWER" - syntax problem

Tags: php, mysql

I try to build a search thru a table in my mysql-database. Because of case sensitivity, I want to use the mysql-function "LOWER" to compare the searchstring with the values from the table.

Here is my Code:

```
$searchparameter = '%' .$parts[$i]. '%';

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT jobunique, joblat, joblng FROM job 
                                                                 WHERE jobdeleted = ? 
                                                                 AND (LOWER(jobtitle) LIKE ?
                                                                 OR LOWER(jobmaincategory) LIKE ?
                                                                 OR LOWER(jobsubcategory) LIKE ?
                                                                 OR LOWER(jobdescription) LIKE ?)");

$stmt->bind_param('issss', $del, $searchparameter, $searchparameter, $searchparameter, $searchparameter);
```

I tryed to use this options:

```
1. $searchparameter = 'LOWER(\'%' .$parts[$i]. '%\')'; 
2. $searchparameter = 'LOWER(%' .$parts[$i]. '%)';
3. $searchparameter = "LOWER(%" .$parts[$i]. "%)";
```

Neither of them works. Can somebody please explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lowercase the PHP variable, then just add the `%`...

```
$searchparameter = '%' .strtolower($parts[$i]). '%';
```

When you bind a value, it is assumed to be a value and your trying to bind a function call as well.

Or if you wanted to stick with useing MySQL `lower()`, I think you can add it to the MySQL and

```
LOWER(jobmaincategory) LIKE LOWER(?)
```

and just use

```
$searchparameter = '%' .$parts[$i]. '%';
```